# Identifier.parse crashes when null value

Tags: android, ibeacon

Basically I have a region which is defined by three parameters.
Sometimes I may specify two or sometimes I may specify three:

```
private void create_region(String UUID, String Major, String Minor) {
    region = new Region("my-beacon-region",
            Identifier.parse(UUID),
            Identifier.parse(Major),
            Identifier.parse(Minor));
}
```

If I pass a null string as Minor for example the program crashes.
How can I solve it? If I do like this it works.

```
region = new Region("my-beacon-region",
                Identifier.parse(UUID),
                Identifier.parse(Major),
                null);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot call `Identifier.parse(Minor)` of Minor is set to null.  But you can pass a null value for the minor.

Comment: If I pass a null value to Minor it crashes `Identifier.parse(null)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create many constractors for the same object in java .ie try to create a constractor with only two params and you initialize the third by yourself to null. And then you can call it with passing only the first two params

Answer (score 0):

Just check if a value is null, and if so, skip the call to `Identifier.parse(...)`:

```
private void create_region(String UUID, String Major, String Minor) {
  Identifier Id1 = null;
  Identifier Id2 = null;
  Identifier Id3 = null;

  if (UUID != null) {
    Id1 = Identifier.parse(UUID);
  }

  if (Major != null) {
    Id2 = Identifier.parse(Major);
  }

  if (Minor != null) {
    Id3 = Identifier.parse(Minor);
  }

  region = new Region("my-beacon-region",
        Id1,
        Id2,
        Id3);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution, just thought there would be a shorter one.